# Download sqllite database from django web app and use in iOS?

Tags: ios, django, sqlite

I'm developing a site-specific installation for an office lobby which will display content on 6 iPads. The installation has several megabytes of data which will be managed by a django webapp. I'm considering different strategies for fetching the content data from the web app. So far, I have simply been dumping the data in to xml format and fetching it via a single http request from the iPad to the content server. I then load all of the content in to memory on the iPad.

I'm beginning to have some concern that I may run in to memory issues as the amount of content grows, and that storing the entire database in-memory won't work. The natural next step is to think about a database on the iPads. I'm using sqllite for the content server. Seems to me that it may be feasible to simply download the entire database file itself and query it directly from the iPad.

**Proposed Approach**

Download the actual sqllite database file nightly from the django content server to each of six iPads used in an office lobby installation.

**Things I like about this approach:**

- It could be really simple. It removes the whole web services layer from the system.
- It protects against network problems nicely. If the network is unavailable, the worst problem is that the iPads display stale data, as apposed to there being no content if the system is network-dependent.

**Things I don't like about this approach**

- I'm not sure how to safely download the file. How to I ensure that the file I'm downloading is in a valid state, and I'm not downloading while someone is updating it?
- I've never heard of anybody doing this, or even considered doing it. It seems like it's far from tried and true.

**My questions**

- Can anyone think of reasons why this is a bad idea?
- How can I safely download a sqllite file with confidence that it's in a valid state?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a Syncing system - perhaps with JSON.

I've done something like this before - I had a central repository server on site that was running my Django web application. The different iPads would sync regularly with the web app's database making sure their local data matched the server data, if not it would update via json.

On the iPad itself, I was using phonegap's SQLITE syntax which worked perfectly for storing the clientside data. But the key was syncing this database via json to the central repositorie's database - rather than physically moving the SQLite db over to the ipad.

Comment: That's the way I would normally do it. But I turn the question back to you: why bother with json and syncing when I could just download an entire exact copy of the database?

Comment: I guess you want an "end of day" or "beginning of day" download - Rather than my needs which required the data to sync on a regular basis during the day. If you want during the day updates I think JSON is the way to go but for a beginning or end of day download I think this is a good idea. I know i've done something like this before but on android - will get back to you